# Installing krb5 package on Windows

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I'm installing simplesamlphp and `php composer.phar install` is throwing an exception due to a lack of ext-krb5 PHP extension.

I didn't find 'krb5' in php.ini; I found the extension here: https://pecl.php.net/package/krb5

I've downloaded the tgz file; how do I activate it?

Comment: Do you have pecl installed?

Comment: No; is there a best-practice way to install pecl on Windows?